# How do I change SQLite file location when using typed dataset in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite

I used vs 2010 wizard in order to connect a SQLite database, and while using the wizard I browsed the db file from specific folder. Now I wish to change the folder but can't find how to do that.

Comment: I dont know the answer, but could u get out of the whole idea of relying on VS wizard and do all db operations manually relying on the connector? Or may be you can even get a good sqlite gui tool

Comment: Use [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the path for the file in  `project's properties -> Settings.settings -> Settings.Designer.cs`
the attribute `global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute`

just change the value and it works.